# Extend Div past relative container to full width of page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to extend a div to the width of a browser window and it's wrapped in a `relative` positioned `div`.

Here's the `HTML` markup:

```
<section class="slider-home">

<div class="overlay"> </div>
<div class="img-product">
    <div class="strapbox-product">
        <h1>
            Farm & Estates
        </h1>
    </div>
    <img src="/assets/img/products/farm-estates.jpg"></img>
</div>

</section>
```

Here's the code for the container:

```
.slider-home {
height: 360px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

And the code for the division I wish to extend

```
.overlay {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 360px;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Or is it this CSS for this division I have to extend?

```
.img-product {
height: 360px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}
```

The CSS code for an image (the cows) within the `img-product` division.

```
.img-product img {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
}
```

And finally a screenshot of the webpage. The cows and the banner I'd like to extend to the full width of the webpage.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried giving .img-product width: 100%? or .slider-home?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do and what the problem is. I have tried this code in jsfiddle and the width: 100% for .overlay expands its container to the full width of the window.

Comment: @msbodetti I have tried but to no avail!

Comment: @DanielD the .slider-home has a overflow:hidden.. maybe take that away and see what it does?

Comment: @DanielD : I posted answer, it might helpyou

Comment: I think the _body_ (or .slider-home's _container_) is less than 100% and he's trying to display that image + heading at the top of the page, covering the full width.. but that's just another guess.

Comment: @LGT I do have a container above these divs with a fixed width of `1140px` but I thought `absolute` attributes remove elements completely from the HTML model and thus the fixed width wouldn't matter?

Comment: Nope, they are relatively positioned to the closest non-static parent (in this case your .slider-home that is relative). For what you want, either move the entire .slider-home to a parent that is or can be 100% wide or set an absolute position where it is and, using JS, calculate and set its (negative) left/right attribute.

Comment: For the second case, the absolute should go on .overlay and then overflow: visible on .slider-home.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this, may be it might help you.

HTML:

```
<section class="slider-home">

<div class="overlay"> </div>
<div class="img-product">
    <div class="strapbox-product">
        <h1>
            Farm & Estates
        </h1>
    </div>
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-cr_BxrxmKrE/TfjZlcf8VBI/AAAAAAAAA5g/JPv6K6XhW0c/s1600/34066_457614643272_609613272_5962233_1924402_n.jpg"></img>
</div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
.slider-home,.img-product,.strapbox-product{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.strapbox-product h1{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    z-index:999999;
    display:block;
}
.img-product img{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}

.overlay{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:black;
    opacity:0.4;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    z-index:999999;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYSS3/1/)